# Trying to install Cadence JACK audio toolbox and I keep getting sent to MATLAB inferface configuration

Tags: pulseaudio, matlab, jack

Okay I've been trying to install Cadence Jack audio toolbox for a couple days now and I've finally had enough every time I try to run the repository seen on KXStudio's website:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https gpgv
```

I end up getting sent to a MATLAB interface configuration.

[image]

I have not a clue why it is doing this. I used to use MATLAB for school but I have know clue what MATLAB has to do with Cadence Jack audio toolbox.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Here are the steps from KXStudio.

Install required dependencies if needed:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https gpgv
```

Remove legacy repos:

```
sudo dpkg --purge kxstudio-repos-gcc5
```

Download package file:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-debian/+archive/kxstudio/+files/kxstudio-repos_10.0.3_all.deb
```

Install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i kxstudio-repos_10.0.3_all.deb
```